# Rails 6.1.4 - Ruby 3.0.1 - ActiveStorage and WebP image format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage, webp

There is no good info about how to setup Rails for serving WebP images with ActiveStorage.

Can someone explain how to do it?

I try:

**application.rb**

```
config.active_storage.web_image_content_types = %w(image/jpeg image/png image/webp 
image/jpg)
```

And in **View**:

```
<% image_tag( f.image_1.variant(resize_to_limit: [800,600], format: :webp) ) %>
```

But this works on development ( I see link to jpeg but when I use right mouse button and "save image as" image is saved as .WebP

On production I see **no image default icon** for browser and link to .jpg

**RoR is dead...**

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by combining format and convert.

```
image.variant(resize_to_limit: [800,600], convert: :webp, format: :webp)
```

The filename in the URL, however, is still `.jpg`, or whatever the original file type is. Haven't been able to figure out how to fix that yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Rails 7, and this works like a charm to me.

```
has_many_attached :images do |attachable|
  attachable.variant :thumb, {resize_to_limit: [500, 500], convert: :webp, saver: { subsample_mode: "on", strip: true, interlace: true, quality: 80 }}
end
```

I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips) as my image processing library. `gem 'ruby-vips', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'`.

You can see all the methods that can be called for `ruby-vips` library [here](https://github.com/janko/image_processing/blob/master/doc/vips.md#methods)

Answer (score 0):

can use 'convert'

```
image.variant(resize_to_limit: [800,600], convert: :webp)
```

Comment: this doesn't work, - On production I see "no image default icon" for browser and link to .jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use `format`, not `convert`. It works for me

```rb
(article.image.variant(resize_to_fill: resize_size, format: 'webp')
```